# Adding data to excel file using apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I gotta add info to a already existing excel file. The reader I built works wonderfully,but every tutorial I've seen just shows how to edit an already existing file or creating a new one. I just need to add 4 cells with info at the end of the file (if the existing file has 2 rows of data I'll add the new data in the third row), and every time it kicks me with an error when trying to access the file, and I'm using the same method to access the file in the reader, and that one works, it doesn't make sense.Here's the code so far:

```
try{
        FileInputStream Album=new FileInputStream(new File("songs.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(Album);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell = null;
        int last=sheet.getLastRowNum();
        Row row =sheet.createRow(last+1);
        Cell cell1=row.createCell(0);
        cell1.setCellValue(name);
        Cell cell2=row.createCell(1);
        cell2.setCellValue(artist);
        Cell cell3=row.createCell(2);
        cell3.setCellValue(duration);
        Cell cell4=row.createCell(3);
        cell4.setCellValue(genre);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/Users/twhit/Documents/U/2016/1ro 2016/POO/IntelliJ/Proyecto1POO/src/Canciones.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I gotta see the exception error message, the stack trace, and the line number that caused it.

Comment: "org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document"   in the line "HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(Album); "

Comment: The error is pretty clear. How do you create `songs.xls`?

Comment: Best guess - your file is zero bytes long, and you're using an old version of Apache POI. (Newer versions give you a different exception if you pass them a zero byte file)

Comment: The file already exists, it's fully functional